# Include parentheses in django 'layout.html'

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates

I have a line in my `layout.html` file:

```html
<a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'index' %}">Watchlist <span class="badge bg-secondary">{{ user.watchlist.all() | length }}</span></a>
```

But the Django template does not allow `()` inside of `{{ }}`. I cannot even do a check in `views.py` and pass it on in the render function as this is the `layout.html` file which is not rendered in any view. How do I perform the `user.watchlist.all()` function then?

Answer (score 0):

What a coincidence! Just one second after posting this I tried removing the `()` leaving behind just `{{ user.watchlist.all | length }}` and it worked perfectly!